# Two figures opening, first one is empty

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
screen_width = 45
screen_height = 45

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (screen_width, screen_height)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.tight_layout()

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax1.set_title("Voltage vs samples")
ax1.grid()
ax1.set_ylabel("Voltage (V)")
ax1.set_xlabel("Samples")

ax2.set_title("Current vs samples")
ax2.set_ylabel("Current (A)")
ax2.set_xlabel("Samples")    
ax2.grid()

# animation def
def animate(i):
    plt.cla()
    ax1.plot(x_vals, y_vals, 'ro')
    ax2.plot(x_vals_1, y_vals_1, 'bo')
    plt.tight_layout

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
```

The code works somewhat. It does animate and update the data how I want it. However, it creates two figures, the first figure is empty and the second figure is the one being updated. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `plt.tight_layout()` is called prior to the creation of a figure, one is created on-the-fly. To avoid the creation of this figure you can simply call `plt.tight_layout()` *after* creating a `Figure` instance, i.e.

```py
# ...
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
plt.tight_layout()
# ...
```

Also note that the line

```py
def animate(i):
    # ...
    plt.tight_layout
```

Does nothing because the function is not called without the trailing parentheses. If you want to call `tight_layout` in your animate function it should be

```py
def animate(i):
    # ...
    plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Thank you,  I will try this out  and get back to you!